# UAC Pops up for program that opens pictures. When did not before how to stop UAC from coming up

Tags: windows-7, administrator, compatibility, uac, gif

Ok problem is that UAC is popping up when opening animated gif files and other picture formats when using windows fax viewer.

Now before I restored to factory default the UAC never came up when opening pictures mainly the animated gif files is what I used it for. But now after the factory default the UAC is coming up for every picture that is linked to the windows fax viewer.

I reinstalled the same 2 files as before === rundll.exe & shimgvw.dll === to the same area as before and put on compatibility mode for windows xp sp2 & sp3 and some of the older ones cause I readed that it may be a compatibility problem. I also tried to created a task to run it but it does not work cause its to open the program itself not from opening the picture files. I also tryed to run as admin and still nothing.

I don't want to disable the UAC but I open a lot of pictures for what I do and I don't like to install extra software unless I need to. So is there any way to stop the UAC from coming up for a program that is open indirectly by another file just like how you open notepad by opening a saved file and not how you can open the program then open the saved file with open? Is there anything that can be done without software.

Comment: I don’t have Windows 7 available currently, but you should be able to show UAC prompts on your regular desktop by taking UAC down one level. Take a screenshot and include it in your question. Don’t worry about embedding the picture, there’s always someone available for that. ;)

Comment: Never mind I reinstalled windows 7 aging it seemed a few files failed to download properly from the disk. So used the usb installer I had and problem fixed. Thanks for your time but finally fixed :)